# CF-IPCountry in .htaccess doesn't appear to work

Tags: .htaccess

I also have a plugin to block Brute Force login attempts. This catches a number of login attempts, when i check the IP's they are from some of the countries I am blocking.

```
#  United States
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry US BuzzOn=1
#  United Kingdom
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry UK BuzzOn=1
#  Great Britain
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry GB BuzzOn=1
#  China
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry CN BuzzOff=1
#  Russia
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry RU BuzzOff=1
#  India
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry IN BuzzOff=1
#  Italy
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry IT BuzzOff=1
#  Thailand
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry TH BuzzOff=1
#  Ukraine
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry UA BuzzOff=1
#  Germany
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry DE BuzzOff=1
#  Turkey
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry TR BuzzOff=1
#  Netherlands
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry NL BuzzOff=1
#  Brazil
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry BR BuzzOff=1
#  Spain
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry ES BuzzOff=1
#  Belarus
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry BY BuzzOff=1
#  Check Republic
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry CZ BuzzOff=1
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

here is a good example for your country blocks :)

```html
## CF-IPCOUNTRY ##
###################
SetEnvIf CF-IPCountry "country" BuzzOff=1
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=BuzzOff
## CF-IPCOUNTRY ##
###################
```